# Parse domain name from URL string

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

How would I parse a domain name in Objective-C?

For example if my string value was "http://www.google.com" I would like to parse out the string "google"

Comment: To clarify requirements - what do you want to get from meta.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: it would be "stackoverflow".

I just discovered splitting a string into an array with "." deliminator and then selecting array[1]. I don't think this is extensible though?

Comment: @pierre

I'd be after just "gov"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the question is a tiny bit invalid. A host is determined by its FQDN (fully qualified domain name) which, in your example, is *www.google.com*. It's not the same as *mail.google.com* or *www.google.info* or *google.com*. To single out "google" is not trivial and does not make much sense from URL perspective.

If you'd like to just parse the URL more-or-less intelligently, I think you can do the following:

1. Use NSURL's -host method to get the scheme and path/query stripped correctly.
2. Use NSString's -componentsSeparatedByString: method to get an array of the domain name's "components".
3. Ignore the last component.
4. If there's only one component left (or it may be enough to take the second-last component), you're done.
5. If the first component contains "www" like *www3*, "ftp", "mail" or something of their kind, you *can* ignore it too if you like. The rest may be of interest, depending on your needs.
6. Test your algorithm against ten thousand URLs to get a sense of futility of this task ;)

Comment: :) thanks for that.

The reason I wanted to know how to do this is because I'm being supplied with a couple of urls from a server. These URL's will 99.9 % of the time be of the format "http://www.thesite.com" so for my purposes this will probably be ok as a shortcut for the time being.
I wanted to display just the site name. It would be nice to have the  URL & the site named returned separately but I have no control over this at the moment

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 7 you can use the NSURLComponents class:

```
NSURLComponents *components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333972/objective-c-parse-domain-name-from-url-string"];
NSAssert([components.host isEqualToString:@"stackoverflow.com"], nil);
```

Comment: Just FYI, `host` includes the subdomain of the given URL. So if the URL would be `www.stackoverflow.com/...`, your assert would fail.